# Why do I get null for LiveData when I launch it again?

Tags: android, android-livedata

I get `aMVoice` from `DetailViewModel` and present it in UI for edit.

I invoke `isChanged()` in `FragmentDetail` and check whether the content of aMVoice is changed.

I can't get the correct result, I find that `val b=(mDBVoiceRepository.getVoiceById(voiceId)).value` always return `null`, why? How can I fix it ?

**Code**

```
class FragmentDetail : Fragment() {   
    private val mDetailViewModel by lazy {
        getViewModel {
            DetailViewModel( provideRepository(mContext), args.voiceId)
        }
    }

    fun isChanged():Boolean{
        mDetailViewModel.checkChanged()
        return mDetailViewModel.isChanged.value!!
    }
}       

class DetailViewModel(private val mDBVoiceRepository: DBVoiceRepository, private val voiceId:Int) : ViewModel() {

   val aMVoice=mDBVoiceRepository.getVoiceById(voiceId)

   private val _isChanged= MutableLiveData<Boolean>(false)
   val isChanged: LiveData<Boolean> = _isChanged

   fun checkChanged(){
         val a=aMVoice.value
         val b=(mDBVoiceRepository.getVoiceById(voiceId)).value   //It's null
        _isChanged.value=!(a==b)

   }
}
    
class DBVoiceRepository private constructor(private val mDBVoiceDao: DBVoiceDao){
    fun getVoiceById(id:Int)=mDBVoiceDao.getVoiceById(id)
}
    
interface DBVoiceDao{   
   @Query("SELECT * FROM voice_table where id=:id")
   fun getVoiceById(id:Int):LiveData<MVoice>
}
    
@Entity(tableName = "voice_table", indices = [Index("createdDate")])
data class MVoice(
    @PrimaryKey (autoGenerate = true) @ColumnInfo(name = "id") var id: Int = 0,
    var name:          String = "",
    var path:          String = ""
)
```

Comment: Does `val a=aMVoice.value` return the correct value?

Comment: Thanks! `val a=aMVoice.value` return correct value

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that you are using live data without observing it, live data does not emit ant data except it has an active observer. So you should create an observer in your fragment instead of manually checking for the value.

Also, it's not necessary to keep variables to detect if the value has changed, live data can do that for you with `distinctUntilChanged()` operator.

So your code should look like something below

```
class FragmentDetail : Fragment() {
    private val mDetailViewModel by lazy {
        getViewModel {
            DetailViewModel(provideRepository(mContext), args.voiceId)
        }
    }
    
    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        observeVoiceChange()
    }

    fun observeVoiceChange() {
        mDetailViewModel.checkChanged().distinctUntilChanged().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer<MVoice> {
            //Do whatever you want when voice changes
        })
    }
}

class DetailViewModel(private val mDBVoiceRepository: DBVoiceRepository, private val voiceId: Int) : ViewModel() {

    fun checkChanged(): LiveData<MVoice> {
        return (mDBVoiceRepository.getVoiceById(voiceId))
    }
}

class DBVoiceRepository private constructor(private val mDBVoiceDao: DBVoiceDao) {
    fun getVoiceById(id: Int) = mDBVoiceDao.getVoiceById(id)
}

interface DBVoiceDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM voice_table where id=:id")
    fun getVoiceById(id: Int): LiveData<MVoice>
}


@Entity(tableName = "voice_table", indices = [Index("createdDate")])
data class MVoice(
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) @ColumnInfo(name = "id") var id: Int = 0,
        var name: String = "",
        var path: String = ""
)
```

once the fragment starts, it should observe for changes in the voice data and return and work with those changes.